# How can I interpret the data in .ARM.attributes in an ELF to get the architecture version and other attributes?

Tags: arm, elf, eabi

I'm most interested in extracting the architecture version, i.e. v5, v5T, etc. I've been referencing [Elf for the ARM Architecture Section 4.3.6 Build Attributes](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf) which has been helpful in getting me up to this point. I can find the start of the .ARM.attributes section and can parse the first key parts of the information: Format-version, Section-length, and vendor-name + null byte, no problem. I get a little lost after that. Below is a snapshot I ran using `hexdump -vC` on an elf compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv5t -O myprog.c -o myprog` for a ARMv5T architecture. The start of the section is 77f0b.

[image]

We can see:
Format-version: A

Section-length: 0x29

Vendor-name: "aeabi"

Obviously, 5T is available in ASCII form at 77f1C, but I'm not sure how to interpret the tag I need to parse to get that value.

Note: Yes, I understand there are tools that I can use to do this, but I need to extract the information in the application I am writing. It already parses the necessary information to make it this far.

Bonus question: Does PowerPC have similar tags? I couldn't find any supporting documentation.

Comment: The "ELF for the ARM Architecture" link is broken and won't redirect. The link to the latest (as of this date) version of that document is https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/aaelf32.pdf - I'd edit it in, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: Also, "Build Attributes" is now section 5.3.6 not 4.3.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These tags are documented in the [Addenda to, and Errata in, the ABI for the ARM Architecture](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/addenda32/addenda32.rst).  For example, under [The target-related-attributes](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/addenda32/addenda32.rst#3352the-target-related-attributes) (section 3.3.5.2), we learn that `Tag_CPU_arch` has value 6, which immediately follows `Tag_CPU_name` (5, preceding the `5T`) in your dump.  Its argument is 3, which again corresponds to ARM v5T, according to the table in the document.  The next tag is `Tag_ARM_ISA_use` (8) with an argument of 1, meaning *The user intended that this entity could use ARM instructions* (whatever this means), and so on.

Note that the integers are encoded in uleb128 format.  This encoding is described in the [DWARF standard](https://dwarfstd.org/Dwarf3Std.php) (in section 7.6 of DWARF 3).  Basically, it's base-128, little endian, and you need to keep reading while the MSB is set.